# Python struct giving incorrect length

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct

Couple of issues with python struct. Please let me know what is correct.

1. [Document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) mentions length of l/L as 4 but when checked with calcsize it gives 8.

   ```
   >>> struct.calcsize('l')
   8
   ```
2. struct module calcsize is giving wrong size. If individual element size is calculated, it's sum is 90 but when calculated together with calcsize it gives 92.

   ```
   >>> struct.calcsize('8s2sIII30s32s6s')
   92

   >>> struct.calcsize('8s')
   8

   >>> struct.calcsize('2s')
   2

   >>> struct.calcsize('III')
   12

   >>> struct.calcsize('30s')
   30

   >>> struct.calcsize('32s')
   32

   >>> struct.calcsize('6s')
   6
   ```

Comment: 1. *"The ‘Standard size’ column refers to the size of the packed value in bytes when using standard size; that is, when the format string starts with one of '<', '>', '!' or '='. When using native size, the size of the packed value is platform-dependent."* 2. Because of padding.

Comment: Understood. I should have paid more attention to documentation. @jonrsharpe please add this as answer. I would like to accept this answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating answer posted by jonrsharpe in comments.

1. The ‘Standard size’ column refers to the size of the packed value in bytes when using standard size; that is, when the format string starts with one of '<', '>', '!' or '='. When using native size, the size of the packed value is platform-dependent.

   ```
   >>> struct.calcsize('l')
   8

   >>> struct.calcsize('=l')
   4
   ```
2. Because of padding. Use = to not use padding.

   ```
   >>> struct.calcsize('=8s2sIII30s32s6s')
   90
   ```