# Python's `struct` byte size calcualtion

Tags: python, struct, byte, decoding

Unfortunately I don't understand the byte size calculation of the `struct` python module.
I use [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) when encoding my values.

```
import struct

struct.calcsize('H') # == 2
struct.calcsize('d') # == 8
```

but

```
struct.calcsize('Hd') # == 16 != 8+2
```

using the encoding together requires 16 bytes instead of 10

What could be/is the reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: See the grey "note" box at the beginning of your linked documentation page about alignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python struct giving incorrect length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048166/python-struct-giving-incorrect-length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help; [Python struct giving incorrect length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048166/python-struct-giving-incorrect-length)

```
struct.calcsize('=Hd')
```

Comment: Thank you and thanks also to @Michael Butscher for the hint.